# "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'" out of nowhere

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

There are a lot of questions about this error, but I haven't found anything relevant.

I compiled and run my project many times and everything was fine, then suddenly, completely out of nowhere, Xcode started to show following error to this line:

```
if let userId = jsonresult["user_id"]{...}
```

I'm using SwiftyJSON.

I'm confused because this error was not here before. I haven't changed anything in this class, I even checked out to the previous commit where app was up and running and now the error is also there.

I tried cleaning the project and deleted derived data, but it does nothing.

Comment: whats the error message you get?

Comment: Ambiguous use of subscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's weird, but sometimes as your error said the compiler cannot infer very well the type of error is occurring. [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#subscript) has **optional-getter** and **Non-optional getter** for access to the elements in the JSON so in  your case you can use the **optional-getter** with its respective conversion to the type, see the following code:

```
if let userId = jsonresult["user_id"].int {...}
```

In the above case I used the `.int` **optional-getter** because I assume that `"user_id"` is a number but you can use the others available like `bool`, `string` or even get the `error` produced.

The **optional-getters** in [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#subscript) are implemented exactly to avoid you have to convert the result of the getter to the type you consider best fit every time like in the following way:

```
if let userId = jsonresult["user_id"] as! Int {...}
```

I hope this help you.